# C++ LNK 2019 error in GLUT game

Tags: c++, glut, lnk2019

Apologies for the poor question title, I wasn't sure how to ask this. I am getting a LNK2019 error when trying to compile my GLUT game and I cannot spot what is causing the error.

The error:
main.obj : `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall asteroid::animateAsteroid(void)" (?animateAsteroid@asteroid@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl idle(void)" (?idle@@YAXXZ)`

asteroid.h

```
class asteroid
{
public:
asteroid(void); //constructer
~asteroid(void); //deconstructer

void Draw();
void createAsteroid();
float generateAsteroidLocation(float a, float b);
void animateAsteroid();
};
```

asteroid.cpp (the trouble function)

```
#include "asteroid.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float asteroidX,asteroidY, V;
bool locationGenerated = false;

asteroid::asteroid(void){

}

asteroid::~asteroid(void){

}
void animateAsteroid(){
float dt = 3500;
float Dx = 25 - asteroidX;
float Dy = 25 - asteroidY;
float Cx = asteroidX + Dx / sqrt(Dx*Dx+Dy*Dy) * V * dt;
float Cy = asteroidY + Dy / sqrt(Dx*Dx+Dy*Dy) * V * dt;
asteroidX = Cx;
asteroidY = Cy;
}
```

Main.cpp (the function where I am getting the error)

```
void idle(void)
{
glutPostWindowRedisplay(glutGetWindow());
Asteroid.animateAsteroid();
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the asteroid.cpp file, you're missing the class name in the method declaration:

```
void asteroid::animateAsteroid(){
...
```

Comment: Correct. I'm embarrassed at how obvious that was. I've been staring at this code for too long. Thank you for your speedy answer :).